# API Management New Developer Portal customization with DevOPS

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a DevOPS pipeline in charge of the deployment of the Azure API Management Developer Portal (the new one).
I need to change some values and content depending on the environment where I publish the developer portal (for example titles of pages, colors, ...).
What is the best practice to avoid managing multiple sources for the portal and having something close to ARM parameter templates?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no out-of-the-box parametrization of the content (please feel free to propose a feature at https://aka.ms/apimwish or at https://github.com/paperbits/paperbits-demo/issues).

However, if I was going to do this today with available tools, I would try to put special sequences into the content (e.g. something like `{{myvariable}}`) and my script would do a simple string replace in JSON document before propagating data to an environment.